# How do I acquire the Eye-gaze location within 2D UWP Apps with HoloLens 2 in C#

Tags: c#, uwp, 2d, hololens, eye-tracking

Online docs like- [2D app design considerations: UI/UX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/devices/designing-for-mr#2d-app-design-considerations-uiux) state that in 2D UWP apps

> When a user gazes towards something or points with a motion controller, a touch hover event will occur. This consists of a PointerPoint where PointerType is Touch, but IsInContact is false.

Which implies that eye-gaze is automatically mapped into your 2D app window on HoloLens 2 and is available through events like the PointerMovedEvent. However, based on my tests I am finding that it is not eye-gaze or even  head based gaze that is passed into the app as a touch hover event, but on the HoloLens 2 it is actually the pointing ray cast by your finger through hand recognition if you point at the 2D app window frame in 3D space.  But if someone is aware of eye-gaze actually being mapped and available inside a 2D UWP app window please let me know.

The next approach would seem to be by leveraging the [SpatialPointPose API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.spatial.spatialpointerpose.eyes?view=winrt-22000#Windows_UI_Input_Spatial_SpatialPointerPose_Eyes)

I am able to grab the starting position of the HoloLens when the app launches and hang on to a stationary reference to that location with the following lines of code:

```
  private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        if (EyesPose.IsSupported() == true)
           {
            var ret = await EyesPose.RequestAccessAsync();
            originLocator = SpatialLocator.GetDefault(); 
            originRefFrame = originLocator.CreateStationaryFrameOfReferenceAtCurrentLocation();
            coordinateSystem = originRefFrame .CoordinateSystem;
           }
         gazeTimer.Start();
    }
```

I have also had success with then using that reference frame to get the coordinate system
and by using a dispatch timer I can then pass that along with a perception time stamp to get a SpatialPointPose object:

From which I can then retrieve the eye gaze origin and gaze direction and display and update the values on screen in xaml textblocks:

```
private void GazeTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
      timestamp = PerceptionTimestampHelper.FromHistoricalTargetTime(DateTime.Now);
      spPose = SpatialPointerPose.TryGetAtTimestamp( coordinateSystem, timestamp );

      if (spPose.Eyes != null && spPose.Eyes.IsCalibrationValid)
            {
                if (spPose.Eyes.Gaze != null)
                {
                   OriginXtextBlock.Text = spPose.Eyes.Gaze.Value.Origin.X.ToString();
                   OriginYtextBlock.Text = spPose.Eyes.Gaze.Value.Origin.Y.ToString();
                   OriginZtextBlock.Text = spPose.Eyes.Gaze.Value.Origin.Z.ToString();
                   DirectionXtextBlock.Text = spPose.Eyes.Gaze.Value.Direction.X.ToString();
                   DirectionYtextBlock.Text = spPose.Eyes.Gaze.Value.Direction.Y.ToString();
                   DirectionZtextBlock.Text = spPose.Eyes.Gaze.Value.Direction.Z.ToString();
                 }
            }
    }
```

However, I haven't found a way to get the UWP 2D app window frame's bounding box location in 3D space or to find specifics on of how the app windows pixel resolution maps to that frame so that I could then somehow resolve the x,y screen coordinates that the eye gaze pointer intersects within the 2d app window.

I'm basically looking to get a similar kind of result with eye gaze as is described in the online help docs (which seems to be actually implemented for the hand recognition pointing finger). But if it is not exposed through something like a pointer event, I am fine with using the SpatialPointPose api if there is a way to complete the last mile of querying the location of the 2D app window frame and resolving the screen coordinates that are being intersected by the eye gaze ray.

Comment: The 2D App will be placed in the Holographic OS shell, and there is nothing API that can obtain the location of the app window from the system shell. Likewise, the Holographic OS shell doesn't provide a way for you to fall back to the head-gaze and start showing the head-gaze cursor to interact with the 2d app. Besides, Microsoft recommends you avoid attaching the cursor directly to the user’s eye-gaze, because this may result in a "fleeing cursor" effect because of slight offsets in the projected eye-gaze signal.

Comment: For more information, please see:[Design recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/eye-gaze-interaction#design-recommendations)

Comment: @HoloSheep Were you able to do this?

Comment: @yaali not yet, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The gaze behavior described in the [2D app design considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/devices/designing-for-mr#2d-app-design-considerations-uiux) documentation is for first generation HoloLens.

On HoloLens 2, Gaze will trigger Pointer events in 2D apps **when the user is in Select mode**. This is to prevent the "inadvertent pop-up or unwanted interaction" problem apps had with Gaze in HoloLens 2. Gaze interaction now occurs only intentionally.

We'll update the docs to clarify.

There is no way for a 2D app to find its location in holographic space, so there is no consistent way to map the SpatialPointerPose into the 2D app's coordinate space. This API is useful only for holographic apps.